istio cant load WasmPlugin filter due to network restrictions
I want to deploy attributegen WasmPlugin, to be able to allow custom classifications of metrics.
However, due to network policies blocking internet access istio isn't able to load the plugin
Probably setting up a specific egress rule and allow access to the https://storage.googleapis.com/istio-build/proxy* endpoint might solve the issue? However, I am not sure how to implement it along with WasmPlugin?
